# Is energy conserved during a Hoffman maneuver?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, orbital-motion, rocket-science, satellites

I have searched a lot about this, and there is a lot out there. But I can't seem to find the answer to this simple question.
The scenario is that i want to change a satellites orbit. So I increase the speed at pergium. Is energy conserved? $T_1 + E_1 = T_2 + E_2$? Or do I have to take in to account that i increase the speed of the satellite?

Comment: Since both the kinetic and potential energy are higher in the higher orbit, energy cannot possibly be conserved.

Comment: But the potential energy is more negative.. ? @Michael

Comment: The sign depends where you put your zero for the potential energy. If it is at $r=\infty$, as is often convention, it will be less negative if the orbit is further away, thus increasing as you shift to higher orbits.

Comment: The title asks about a Hoffman maneuver. Are you asking about a Hohmann transfer, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Hohmann transfer, first, the kinetic energy is increased at the lower (circular) orbit. This results in the satellite having too much kinetic energy for a circular orbit at the small radius. As a result, it will go to an elliptical orbit, where at the outermost point, it will have traded some of its kinetic energy for potential (gravitational) energy. At this point, the kinetic energy is increased again, so that the satellite now has enough kinetic energy for a circular orbit at this point further away.

In conclusion, we increase the kinetic energy twice. Some of the total kinetic energy is converted to potential energy, which does not change the energy in the system. Thus, overall, the total energy is increased and not conserved.

Comment: This is not quite right: the kinetic energy at the final orbit is actually smaller than its initial value, though the increase in potential energy is larger.

Comment: You are correct, I edited the answer.